# Failed to download package files error in software updater

Tags: apt, updates

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 3 LTS, GNOME Version 3.36.8 on a Surface 2017.  When trying to get updates using Software updater have been getting the error that reads "Failed to download package files error : Check your internet connection."

"Main Server" is already selected for where to download from.

Tried all the steps here and didn't fix: https://forum.zorin.com/t/failed-to-download-package-files/14565/9

Please let me know if you can help.  I'd like to get updates and also upgrade to the latest LTS (not prompting for that).

Thank you!

**Here is output of sudo apt update:**
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease
Ign:3 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:4 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:8 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tj/bugfixes/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [277 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [391 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,988 B]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [77.6 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 1,165 kB in 2s (583 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
150 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

**Output of sudo apt upgrade**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libb2-1 libfwupdplugin1 libmd4c0 libqt6core6 libqt6dbus6 libqt6gui6
libqt6labsqmlmodels6 libqt6network6 libqt6networkauth6 libqt6opengl6
libqt6qml6 libqt6qmllocalstorage6 libqt6qmlmodels6 libqt6qmlworkerscript6
libqt6quick6 libqt6quickcontrols2-6 libqt6quickcontrols2impl6
libqt6quicklayouts6 libqt6quicktemplates2-6 libqt6sql6 libqt6sql6-sqlite
libqt6svg6 libqt6test6 libqt6websockets6 libqt6widgets6 libts0
linux-headers-5.14.11-surface linux-headers-5.14.14-surface
linux-headers-5.14.8-surface linux-image-5.14.11-surface
linux-image-5.14.14-surface linux-image-5.14.8-surface
qml6-module-qt-labs-qmlmodels qml6-module-qt5compat-graphicaleffects
qml6-module-qtqml qml6-module-qtqml-models qml6-module-qtqml-workerscript
qml6-module-qtquick qml6-module-qtquick-controls qml6-module-qtquick-layouts
qml6-module-qtquick-localstorage qml6-module-qtquick-templates
qml6-module-qtquick-window qt6-gtk-platformtheme qt6-qpa-plugins wireguard
wireguard-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386
libegl1:i386 libfwupdplugin5 libgbm1:i386 libigdgmm11:i386 libva2:i386
libwacom-bin-surface libwacom-common-surface libwacom2-surface
libwacom9-surface libwayland-server0:i386 linux-headers-5.19.7-surface
linux-image-5.19.7-surface mesa-va-drivers:i386 va-driver-all:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
alsa-ucm-conf base-files bolt command-not-found deja-dup fwupd fwupd-signed
gdb gdbserver gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-mutter-6 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7
gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-pc
grub-pc-bin grub2-common gtk-update-icon-cache gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin
gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs iio-sensor-proxy
initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core iptsd
isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common kactivitymanagerd kmod language-pack-en
language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
libasound2 libasound2:i386 libasound2-data libatopology2 libc-bin
libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libfprint-2-2 libfwupd2
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
libjcat1 libkeyutils1 libkmod2 libkworkspace5-5 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy
libmm-glib0 libmutter-6-0 libnautilus-extension1a libnetplan0 libnm0
libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd
libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp libqmi-glib5
libqmi-proxy libqt5webkit5 libsensors-config libsensors5 libsensors5:i386
libsnmp-base libsnmp35 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libtss2-esys0 libudev1
libudev1:i386 libwacom-surface libxnvctrl0 lintian linux-base linux-firmware
linux-headers-5.14.14-surface linux-headers-surface
linux-image-5.14.14-surface linux-image-surface linux-surface-secureboot-mok
locales login modemmanager mutter mutter-common nautilus nautilus-data
netplan.io network-manager network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
openssh-client passwd pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-utils python-apt-common python3-apt python3-commandnotfound
python3-distupgrade python3-dnspython python3-software-properties
python3-update-manager sbsigntool snapd software-properties-common
software-properties-gtk steam-launcher steam-libs-amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386
systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs
tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-drivers-common
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk udev ufw
unattended-upgrades update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier
update-notifier-common wget xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
150 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 standard security update
Need to get 158 MB/506 MB of archives.
After this operation, 486 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 libwacom-surface amd64 2.4.0-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:2 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 libwacom-common-surface amd64 2.4.0-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:3 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 libwacom9-surface amd64 2.4.0-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:4 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 libwacom-bin-surface amd64 2.4.0-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:5 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 libwacom2-surface amd64 2.4.0-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:6 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 iptsd amd64 0.5.1-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:7 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-headers-5.19.7-surface amd64 5.19.7-surface-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:8 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-headers-surface amd64 5.19.7-surface-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:9 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-headers-5.14.14-surface amd64 5.14.14-surface-3
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:10 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-image-5.19.7-surface amd64 5.19.7-surface-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:11 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-image-surface amd64 5.19.7-surface-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:12 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-image-5.14.14-surface amd64 5.14.14-surface-3
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
Err:13 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release/main amd64 linux-surface-secureboot-mok amd64 20220427-1
401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/ec990d40-39ef-4a73-8b2d-e0d2860b0d2c?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171411Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=fcfbb15c7633013352fbc76d9363f0e3ca092d8068cf947d4b18728ce73c41a9&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=libwacom-surface_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/9a024a27-c3c8-46e7-8c4a-18a6114138e0?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171411Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=c82229b76060deae186c624403c4a2c6efd2f33ca2017888309bbf142a471e59&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=libwacom-common-surface_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/9ac33f87-8963-45cf-b5b2-4cb313cc28ff?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171411Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=0353055045d007a30f2b49a4af1e7187b9068a718f05839d1b80dc127f657385&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=libwacom9-surface_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/34697f30-d54c-4905-ad72-c27a10baa98d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171411Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=b0e3d30f723dfd51999be9957856e5365a2ebd954e627ff3908b8ecccd506fbb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=libwacom-bin-surface_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/139604852/9075c63a-d08c-4da3-98c0-b920513043f8?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171411Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=b06a1e7130dd3e55bc21717d895f8c7b0d69869856418ca9828d7e193770b802&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139604852&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=libwacom2-surface_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/261858706/9e436241-8b65-4228-aad9-85d540af422d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171411Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=1ce7ebcd7c8f40e3d4665d20abadf4da9124d9f08c414186c0e6e2d193f9335c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=261858706&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=iptsd_0.5.1-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/155009767/10c04fe3-d3fb-4e45-ae9f-20261f44fed1?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171411Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=757fbdf5c4159a51b945e8d98c4fa62c9700940467b81a08558f90994ebac03c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=155009767&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-headers-5.19.7-surface_5.19.7-surface-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/155009767/4fc3cbfb-d133-4935-bc2a-d6740cf46681?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171412Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=c8f2b8b8c63ef0e22b542ad27ee95c361e92d473e95d8daa733ce96e00e21795&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=155009767&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-headers-surface_5.19.7-surface-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/155009767/2cb6ab71-6620-43b8-b3f2-cb4f2fa933fa?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171412Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=2f863d1ac392f05b1e951f045432686d504ef6cf4567b438fb0cf6e23d54ebd1&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=155009767&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-headers-5.14.14-surface_5.14.14-surface-3_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/155009767/a51607a5-fad3-4419-b2a0-17478ae1e9ed?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171412Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=e3e07cdd1bbd63abda348c30ae21f99286c6d3665fd5e8df895578e37219b44e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=155009767&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-image-5.19.7-surface_5.19.7-surface-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/155009767/8493827e-fb98-4f9a-a987-f744b562668a?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171413Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=e2b95e635865e28233a6f964bd59515ef82da7b708445afdc3655e40cade0158&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=155009767&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-image-surface_5.19.7-surface-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/155009767/6c9e68be-25dc-40d3-b81b-963fe399b331?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171412Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=bc1314603684442364ba9c24dc8ab3c723a184dac3d1b6838b44ed7c2c0a6031&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=155009767&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-image-5.14.14-surface_5.14.14-surface-3_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/211351605/e21fbc76-7a83-4c26-9e01-7e194b7af7ae?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A/20220910/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220910T171413Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=7c5094bec9159271421ea36ae029d27f3de68b3f24e1951a204c6229854381cd&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=211351605&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=linux-surface-secureboot-mok_20220427-1_amd64.deb&response-content-type=application/octet-stream  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.110.133 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Thank you, I have just edited to include this.

Comment: Your output says `150 packages can be upgraded`. That's seriously bad, and the high number suggests that it has been bad for a long time.

Comment: No download error so far. Edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Thank you again! Just included.  Let me know if that helps.  And yes, it has been many months that I got this error message, but I guess I didn't worry about it?  Probably should have!

Comment: Problem #1: Disable the source `https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial` It's over five years old. You don't use Xenial.

Comment: Problem #2: Disable the source `http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco`. That's been out of support for over three years.

Comment: Problem #3: Disable the source `https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian`. That seems to be where most of your error messages are coming from.

Comment: The lesson here is that most of what you need to know is already in your output. After you have disabled those three sources, then `apt update` and `apt full-upgrade`. If you still get error messages that you do not understand, then add the complete output of both to your question.

Comment: Ok sounds good, thank you!  Can you please explain how I disable those sources?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out by unchecking the box in Software Updater for 2 of the 3 sources (#1 didn't appear).  Seems like all is working now.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Update Ubuntu,I faced the same issue, after sometime i downloaded a jamjelly fish version from Official ubuntu site and Booted my system with it

Comment: Thank you!  I would prefer not to re-install everything if possible.